# AWS: Why I am unable to assign a custom domain to the nested stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am trying to integrate a custom domain to the `HTTP API` I am developing with `AWS API Gateway` and `AWS Lambda`. I m using the `AWS SAM` template. There I have a root stack and nested stacks.

For this question I will use a code piece with a one nested stack. There, this is how I want the URL end points to be

1. root stack - api.example.com
2. nested stack - api.example.com/nested

Below is my code

**Root stack**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f24xxxx921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-0xxxxx2d


Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String
  
  #Dont create this domain in the AWS Console manually, so it will fail here
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Default: api.example.com

Resources:
  AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Domain:
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxx:certificate/xxxx-420d-xxxx-b40d-xxxx
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: xxxxxxxxxxx
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer

 
  AuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/testfile.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        Gateway:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

  NestedStackTwo:
    DependsOn: AuthGatewayHttpApi
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: nested_stack.yaml
      Parameters:
        FirebaseProjectId: !Ref FirebaseProjectId
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
```

**Nested stack**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxx

Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String
  
  DomainName:
    Type: String

Resources:

  AuthGatewayHttpApi2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Domain:
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        BasePath: two
        EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxx:certificate/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer

  GetAllPromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-getall.getAllPromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/getall
            Method: get
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi2
```

However I cant get this to work because the nested stack fails to create. Below is the error

```
CREATE_FAILED                      AWS::CloudFormation::Stack         NestedStackTwo
                                                    

Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1 xxxxx:stack/aws-restapi-NestedStackTwo-8KBISZRAVYBX/a3fcc010-0ce4-11ec-9c90-0e8a861a6983 was not successfully created:

 The following resource(s) failed to create: [ApiGatewayDomainNameV234ac706a57]
```

I believe this is happening because the root stack creates the domain and the nested stack is trying to re-create it instead of reusing the same.

But, here is the fun fact; if i use the AWS API GATEWAY web console, I can do this in no time.

How can I get this to work in `aws-sam` ?

**UPDATE**

Following the advice from the user LRutten, I came up with the following code for the nested stack.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-xxxxxx
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-xxxxx

Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String
  
  DomainName:
    Type: String

Resources:

  AuthGatewayHttpApi2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer
  
  MyApiMapping:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping'
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref DomainName
      ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi2
      Stage: prod
  
  MyDomainName:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::DomainName'
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref DomainName
      DomainNameConfigurations:
        - EndpointType: REGIONAL
          CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:716460586643:certificate/bac44716-420d-431b-b40d-01378f20432d


  GetAllPromotionsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/promotions/promotions-getall.getAllPromotions
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllPromotionsAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /promotions/getall
            Method: get
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi2
```

This ended up with the following error

```
Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:716460586643:stack/aws-restapi-NestedStackTwo-14SAYLRO1WD1D/62336020-xx-xx-a04e-x was not successfully created:

The following resource(s) failed to create: [MyDomainName, MyApiMapping].
```

Comment: ty for showing us a simple example for a nested stack.

Comment: @petey: You are welcome. Any suggestion on what I should do?

Comment: @petey: Hello?....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed SAM always creates the domain when you specify it's name there. It stated in the docs as well.

To get around this, you can omit the whole domain configuration in the `AWS::Serverless::HttpApi` resource and write the resources created by SAM yourself. So add a section with

```
Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
Properties: 
  ApiId: String
  ApiMappingKey: String
  DomainName: String
  Stage: String
```

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-apimapping.html)

Make sure the `Stage` property in the ApiMapping is also present in the `StageName` property of the API.

<strike>And a</strike>

```
Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::DomainName
Properties: 
  DomainName: String
  DomainNameConfigurations: 
    - DomainNameConfiguration
  MutualTlsAuthentication: 
    MutualTlsAuthentication
  Tags: Json
```

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-domainname.html)

Manually adding these without having the domain itself defined twice should do the trick.

Edit: woops wasn't really thinking straight. You should of course only have the mapping, not the domain name itself again :P.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. `you can omit the whole domain configuration` - You mean at the nested stack? Or the root stack? Or in both?

Comment: Sorry,  should've been more specific:P Omit it in the nested stack  only.

Comment: I made the changes and faced another error. I updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: Can you provide the error message itself also in the post? You can find it in the cloudformation console in the 'events' tab of your deleted (nested) stack.

Comment: Also updated the post, since it didn't make sense to add the DomainName again :P

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that there is no stagename `prod` defined in your API definition? If so, make sure to add a `StageName: prod` to your api in the nested stack and make sure that the ApiMapping waits until the stage is created by optionally providing a `DependsOn: AuthGatewayHttpApi2ProdStage`, following the naming convention given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-generated-resources-httpapi.html)

Comment: wow, This is a one big messed up technology LRutten. I tried, no good. Now i get hit with `Embedded stack 
 arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east- 
 1:716460586643:stack/aws- 
 restapi-NestedStackTwo-1XYDWU9T 
 D8M1M/70e53da0-0d71-11ec-8a0e-0 
 a619e90e3eb was not 
 successfully created: The 
 following resource(s) failed to 
 create: [MyApiMapping]. `

Comment: Yeah but can you post the event stating the error from the nested stack. The event you post here is from the main stack.

Comment: Yes, but in cloudformation I cant find the nested stack. It is like it was never created.

Comment: Because, it also throws this `The following resource(s) failed to create:  [NestedStackTwo]. Rollback requested by user.  `

Comment: wow, I managed to get this to work. I was missing `ApiMappingKey` in my code. Thanks a lot for everything. I have sent you a LinkedIn connection request with a message, let's keep in touch.

Comment: Just wanted to ask, when building a REST API, AWS API Gateway offers REST and HTTP API options. I'm moving forward with HTTP because that's what I managed to fix the Firebase Authentication. You know, what I want is to have the server call codes that make the communication between the client app and the database. So HTTP gateway serves the same right? The document says it's actually better than the REST API offered by the API Gateway

Comment: Yeah correct. For basic stuff http api's are better. It does not have full feature parity yet with REST apis but it's good enough.

Comment: Not sure what you meant as features are missing. Anyway all we need is to access the lambda calls . So that's good?

Comment: Great. Thank you. 